# Restrain SSPI Auth to one page, Apache conf

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, .htaccess

I need to have SSPI auth on the adress " / ", but not on the rest of the site

I've tried this configuration :

```
 <Location "/">
        AuthType SSPI
        AuthName "XXXX"
        SSPIAuth On
        SSPIAuthoritative On
        SSPIOfferBasic On
        Require valid-user
    </Location>

    <Location "/?*">
        AuthType none
    </Location>
```

But it's not doing what I want. Instead of having one login entry point, it pop auth like 4 times and doesn't log me.

Any idea ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LocationMatch ^/$ in the first block and nothing else.